# Unable to unpack archive on plesk

Tags: .net, plesk

> Unable to extract //Publish.zip: Unable to unpack archive
>   D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\nepalicompany.com\Publish.zip to
>   D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\nepalicompany.com at (UnpackArchive::onRunAsUser
>   line 2699) at Unable to unpack archive
>   D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\nepalicompany.com\Publish.zip(UnpackArchive::onRunAsUser
>   line 2702)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tfkN.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try editing your question, Steve (back from space) !

Answer (score 0):

It seems that 7-Zip, which is used by Plesk to work with archives, is not properly installed on the server.

To resolve it, [download and (re)install 7-Zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/) and make sure that installation directory, for example, `C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip` has all permissions for user `psacln`.

Or replace `7.exe` and `7z.dll` in `%plesk_bin%` folder with ones taken 7-zip installation directory.